# How to check queue length of android Messenger

Tags: java, android, service, messenger

I had a android service, it communication with client with Messenger (because the service have to execute the command serially so chose the messenger), messenger will queue the tasks if there are multiple requests at the same time. The client want to check the server queue length to decide whether to line up, so how to check the queue length of messenger?

Exp code:

```
public class MessengerService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "Serial Service";
private static final int MSG_EXECMD = 0x1;

private Messenger mMessenger;
private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
private Handler mHandler;
private Message mmessageToClient;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBind");
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onUnbind pid=" + android.os.Process.myPid());
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("serial-work-thread");
    mHandlerThread.start();
    mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msgfromClient) {
            Message msgToClient = Message.obtain(msgfromClient);
            mmessageToClient = Message.obtain(msgfromClient);
            switch (msgfromClient.what) {
                case MSG_EXECMD:
                    msgToClient.what = MSG_EXECMD;
                    try {
                        //takes time here about 3s
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        msgToClient.arg1 = 0;
                        msgToClient.arg2 = msgfromClient.arg2;
                        msgfromClient.replyTo.send(msgToClient);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error:" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    mMessenger = new Messenger(mHandler);
    super.onCreate();
}
}
```

Comment: you cannot do that

Comment: @pskink Is there any other way?

Comment: @pskink because some command takes about 60 or 70 seconds,and if these commands be request repeatedly,the service will almost died,its also very bad for other client.

Comment: @pskink but this replyTo can't be used for the client which in the mMessenger queue,right? or you mean create a new thread in handleMessage to execute time-consuming command and manage all client queues manually ?